# Does a Sliders episode bring them to The Lost World: Jurassic Park?

Tags: jurassic-park, sliders, the-lost-world-jurassic-park

In *Sliders* season 4 episode 14, "Mother and Child", they run into a building that looks exactly (as far as I can tell) like the visitor's center in *The Lost World: Jurassic Park*.

Does anybody know for sure if it's the same set?

Comment: Season 4 they were filming on the Universal Studios backlot, and Lost World was Universal Studios, and they were around the same time, so... I'd say odds are good, but can't 100% confirm.

Comment: The JP wiki says that it was "*Sometime after production had wrapped on the The Lost World and before the set was re-purposed for Jurassic Park III, the Village in its entirety was used as a filming location for the 14th episode in season 4 of the TV show Sliders.*"; https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Worker_Village

Answer (score 5):

In a word, yes. Parts of the episode were filmed on a backlot where the InGen Facility and Workers Village sets hadn't yet been stripped. The podcast "[Jurassic Mysteries](https://player.fm/series/jurassic-minutes-podcast/jurassic-mysteries-ep-010-rewind-tlw-sliders-worker-village-special)" (Episode 10) mentions some of the features that can be seen in the episode (transcribed below).

> Operations building external and internal shots in first 27 seconds of episode
> Emerge from the helipad end of operations building and there's no tree beside building
> Set still has mould on it!
> Doors have been removed. I wonder if they were kept by someone in production
> Because roof curves up from front windows we can see large glass windows above the concrete wall the Mural was painted on.
> They turn left when entering and head to window on unused end of lobby. I'd always thought they were at the end of the building looking out at the hill beside the building. But it's the lobby wall they're looking through. This is where nick stood shining light off into space after looking at Mural.
> Note Comms room glass wall and door still in place behind them. So we still don't see the unused area of the building.
> Room is still full of vines.
> Giant tumbleweeds litter the lobby.
> Mouldy blinds over windows
> Hallway runs full length of operations building. There's a room and a door between Comms centre and rear helipad door
> Centre wall where mural was is curved
> Rear hallway has floor to ceiling windows running along it also. Would be stunning during its operation. Barred windows on roof? Same bars seen earlier above lobby.
> There's a walkway leaving building and going up a hill. Fire escape? Path to another structure? Note no perimeter fence.

They also did an hour long teardown of the episode [here](https://player.fm/series/jurassic-minutes-podcast/tlwm-sliders-worker-village-bonus-show).

---

Eagle-eyed viewers will spot some boxes and crates stamped with the InGen logo.

[image]